# Entity framework foreign key

Tags: entity-framework

I have 2 classes

```
public class Person
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public string FirstName { get; set; }        
    public string LastName { get; set; }        
    public string Email { get; set; } 
}
```

and

```
public class PersonWebsite
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public int PersonId{ get; set; } 
}
```

I've seen stuff like this being done before

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public string FirstName { get; set; }        
    public string LastName { get; set; }        
    public string Email { get; set; } 

    public ICollection<PersonWebsite> PersonWebsites{ get; set; }

}
```

How could I go about implementing the code that when a Person is initialized, the PersonWebsites List will automatically be initialised and get all the PersonWebsite objects that have the same PersonId as the class that calls it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lazy Loading:**

You can make `PersonWebsites` property virtual:

`public virtual ICollection<PersonWebsite> PersonWebsites{ get; set; }`

Entity framework will load it from the database as soon as it's required.
Also this method requires you to have lazy loading enabled which is by default:

`DbContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;`

**Eager Loading:**

You can use include to force entity framework to load `PersonWebsites` on the first query:

`DbSet.Include(p => p.PersonWebsites);`

Comment: When I load the person using uow.People.GetById(id); the websites are null? Do I have to add anything to the database table?

Comment: Have you setup `Person` and `PersonWebsites` relationship? If not the Andrew's answer sets that up. Then in your DbContext for example you can use `People.Include(p => p.PersonWebsites).Find(id)`

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to change your PersonWebsite class like this, in order to navigate to the person from the PersonWebsite object (using Lazy-Loading):

```
public class PersonWebsite
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    public int PersonId{ get; set; } 
    public virtual Person Person {get;set;}
}
```